# Can I define different text styles in a resource instead of a renderer?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Currently I am using this renderer to style the size of text:

```
<local:StyledLabel YAlign="Center" Text="Buttons" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />                     

public class StyledLabel : Label
{
    public StyledLabel()
    {
        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
        {
            Style = Device.Styles.CaptionStyle;
        }
        else if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
        {
            Style = Device.Styles.ListItemTextStyle;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way that I can do something similar in a resource XAML so that the size might be different for iOS or Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XAML you can specify different values like so:

```
<local:StyledLabel YAlign="Center" Text="Buttons" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
    <local:StyledLabel.Style>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Style">
            <OnPlatform.Platforms>
                <On Platform="iOS" Value="{StaticResource CaptionStyle}" />
                <On Platform="Android" Value="{StaticResource ListItemTextStyle}" />
            </OnPlatform.Platforms>
        </OnPlatform>
    </local:StyledLabel.Style>
  ...
</local:StyledLabel>
```

More information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/essential-xaml-syntax

By the way, `YAlign` is deprecated, you should `VerticalTextAlignment`.

Comment: I'm sorry I should have mentioned that I would like to do this in a resource file.  As I didn't mention it then I will create another question.

Comment: This doesn't matter, principle stays the same